# JSF: invoke action after value change

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces-3

In the bad old days in my codebase we relied quite heavily on event requeuing, which I suspect worked due to implementation details in ICEfaces or MyFaces rather than standard-specified behavior. One thing we used to do frequently was this kind of thing:

```
<ice:inputText value="#{bb.frequency}" valueChangeListener="#{bb.valueChanged}"/>
```

The goal is to arrange for `retune` to be called after `setFrequency` whenever the frequency changes.

Then we had some fairly disgusting code in the backing bean which would requeue the event. It usually looked something like this:

```
class BB {
  // this happens first, thanks to UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES
  public void setFrequency(Frequency f) {
    this.model.f = f;
  }

  public void valueChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    if (event.getOldValue().equals(event.getNewValue())
      return; // nothing changed, so leave

    if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPhaseId() != INVOKE_APPLICATION) {
      OurMagicEventUtils.requeueEvent(event, INVOKE_APPLICATION);
    }
    else {
      // do the post-setter work here (the setter happened recently during 
      // UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES so we're up-to-date by here
      this.model.retune();
    }
  }
}
```

This isn't a good way to live. I haven't found a reliable way to requeue events for later phases and it clearly isn't the kind of thing people do. I see two solutions:

1. Move the retune intelligence to the `BB#setFrequency` method.

   I can't get away with this in many cases because I'm directly addressing a lower-level model class and I don't want to disturb its behavior for other clients.
2. Create a custom component and move the logic into the `setFoo` method there.

   I don't love this because there are a lot of issues with Mojarra and custom components when embedded in other containers. It also seems like overkill for what I need to do—I literally just need to call `retune` after setting some properties.
3. Create backing beans for everything. Delegate most methods directly to the inner thing, but catch `setFoo` and perform the retune there. This is very similar to what we used to do, and it means a lot of boilerplate, wrappers, and glue code, so I don't love it.

In my mind I imagine something like this:

```
<ice:inputText value="#{bb.frequency}" afterChange=#{bb.retune}"/>
```

but that obviously doesn't work, nor would attaching an `<f:actionListener>` since that requires a class name but has no association to whatever you're currently doing, and besides it can only be set on `UICommand`s which `UIInput`s are not.

What's the elegant/correct way to solve this dilemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using JSF2 already, just use `<f:ajax>`.

```
<ice:inputText value="#{bb.frequency}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bb.retune}"/>
</ice:inputText>
```

with

```
public void retune(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) { // Note: the argument is optional.
    // ...
}
```

This will be invoked during invoke action phase when the HTML DOM `change` event has occured.

Comment: Thanks once again for a great, direct answer. How do you recommend someone actually learn JSF fully? I feel like I learn bits and pieces around the web, but even after three years using it professionally I still have many gaps in my knowledge. How should I go about sealing those gaps, apart from S.O.?